# Javascript for Automation (OSA) Yosemite: privilege error for certain StandardAddition commands

Tags: javascript, applescript, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

In Yosemite it now is possible to use [JavaScript for automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html) as well as Applescript. I am having trouble with certain StandardAdditions commands. E.g. from the Contacts application I can use **displayAlert**, but not **displayNotification**. Both are in the StandardsAdditions dictionary. When running these commands through the ScriptEditor I don't get these issues.

For the commands that fail I get at runtime: **Error -10004: A privilege violation occurred**.

Example code in **JavaScript**:

```
ScriptEditor = Application("Script Editor");
ScriptEditor.includeStandardAdditions = true;

app = Application("Contacts"); // or e.g. "Calendar", "System Events", "Finder"
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

// -- testing: displayAlert()
ScriptEditor.displayAlert("Hello world!"); 
app.displayAlert("Hello world!"); // success, no privilege error

// -- testing: displayNotification()
ScriptEditor.displayNotification("Hello world!"); 
//app.displayNotification("Hello world!"); // Error -10004: A privilege violation occurred.

// --- testing: say()
ScriptEditor.say("Hello world!");
//app.say("Hello world"); // Error -10004: A privilege violation occurred.

// --- testing: beep()
ScriptEditor.beep(1);
//app.beep(1); // Error -10004: A privilege violation occurred.
```

When using the equivalent code in **AppleScript** I do not get privilege violation errors:

```
tell application "Script Editor" to display alert "from Script Editor" -- with Script Editor icon
tell application "Contacts" to display alert "from contacts" -- with Contacts icon

tell application "Script Editor" to display notification "from Script Editor" -- with Script Editor icon
tell application "Contacts" to display notification "from contacts" -- with Script Editor icon (!)
```

What I notice in that case though is that the Contacts **alert** shows up with the **Contacts icon** (and Contacts app is activated), but the Contacts **notification** shows up with the **Script Editor** icon (and the Contacts app is not activated).

Using Yosemite 10.10.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I get the same result using Apple's sample snippet from the doc page (under "Scripting Additions") if I replace `.currentApplication()` (ie Script Editor) with anything else. I assume this is intentional (can't cause another app to "say" stuff?) but wish it were documented with rationale.

Comment: If that were the case, the dialog and alert should be similarly restricted.  "Mail Requires Your Password" as a dialog is far more dangerous.

Comment: Part of the comment by @BenZotto gives the practical answer: User `Application.currentApplication()` instead of another application to run `displayNotification()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that AppleScript is using inheritance. You can tell any application to "display notification", but the call ends up getting passed up the hierarchy to Script Editor (or a script applet) which understands the message. The JavaScript implementation doesn't support inheritance to my knowledge. I'm not really well-versed in the JavaScript side of the OSA world. :)

tl;dr: Contacts can't actually do what you're trying to make it do, it just works in AppleScript because AppleScript is that amazing. :)

If you look at the replies log in Script Editor, you can see the inheritance happen live.

Comment: Why does it work for `app.displayAlert()` but not for `app.displayNotification()`?